# plot individual peaks after gaussian curve fitting with python-lmfit

Tags: python, gaussian, lmfit

From this piece of code I can print the final fit with "out.best_fit", what I would like to do now, is to plot each of the peaks as individual gaussian curves, instead of all of them merged in one single curve.

```
from pylab import *
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_errors
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel, SkewedGaussianModel
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from numpy import *

fit_data = interp1d(x_data, y_data)

mod = LinearModel()
pars = mod.make_params(slope=0.0, intercept=0.0)
pars['slope'].set(vary=False)
pars['intercept'].set(vary=False)


x_peak = [278.35, 334.6, 375]
y_peak = [fit_data(x) for x in x_peak]


i = 0
for x,y in zip(x_peak, y_peak):
    sigma = 1.0
    A = y*sqrt(2.0*pi)*sigma
    prefix = 'g' + str(i) + '_'

    peak = GaussianModel(prefix=prefix)

    pars.update(peak.make_params(center=x, sigma=1.0, amplitude=A))

    pars[prefix+'center'].set(min=x-20.0, max=x+20.0) 

    pars[prefix+'amplitude'].set(min=0.0)
    mod = mod + peak
    i += 1

out = mod.fit(y_data, pars, x=x_data)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_data, out.best_fit, '--')
```

Plot of the global fit:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What are `x_data` and `y_data`?

Comment: Sorry, they are just two lists for the x and y data.

Comment: Can't you get the fit parameters from `out`? They must be stored somewhere in order to compute the y-values of the fit. Then if you manage to extract the fit parameters you can plot the single Gaussian distributions.

Comment: I could guess that :) I am more interested in the actual values.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Cleb how would you suggest I could upload the data? Sorry this is my first post and I didn't know I could attach an extra file.

Comment: a_guest I was looking for a straighforward solution without writing any extra function but I followed your advice and yes, I was able to plot the individual curves from the fit parameters. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this after your fit:

```
components = out.eval_components(x=x_data)
for model_name, model_value in components.items():
    plt.plot(x_data, model_value)

# or more simply, if you prefer:
plt.plot(x_data, components['g0_'])
plt.plot(x_data, components['g1_'])
...
```

That is, `ModelResult.eval_components()` for a composite model will return a dictionary with keys that are the prefixes of the component models, and values that are the calculated model for that component.

Comment: Thank you M Newville, that's what I was looking for. However, I am not an expert but I think that your suggestion don't work with my code because I am using a builtin model. Anyways, I need to fit with my own models so I'll have to use the Model class and then I think I could use your solution.

Comment: ModelResult.eval_components() should work with any composite model, including those using builtin models.